# how to do dll delay loading in MinGW64

Tags: mingw-w64

I'm building my project which depends on some dlls for which I hope to do delay load so that when functions in those dlls are actually called will those dlls be downloaded onto the file system.

Both my project and the external libs are built in MinGW and according to my research delay load is not supported on MinGW but supported on MinGW64.

So I'll start to move everything to MinGW64. The dlls I built have .dll .def and .dll.a, does any one have any idea is there any special option to the MinGW64 linker for delayloading?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?